# couldn't connect to Yoctoproject git

Tags: git, yocto

When i try to connect below error is coming...

```
Running: git remote add origin git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
Running: git fetch origin --depth=3 tags/dylan-9.0.2:tags/dylan-9.0.2
fatal: unable to connect to git.yoctoproject.org:
git.yoctoproject.org[0: 140.211.169.56]: errno=Connection refused
```

Comment: Please check your network connnection etc. Or it could be a temporary network issue.

Comment: What does `ssh -vT git@git.yoctoproject.org` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to yocto repo (the repo is read-only for people like you and me), but only clone it.

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
```

You can then switch into the poky directory to do whatever you want (but not push). Normaly, origin is already setted, and you can check that with

```
$  git remote -v
or even see the log with 
$  git log
```

To make push, set the origin to your own repo's location.